# jQuery Validation Arguments

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

jQuery Validation plugin has "element" argument for required rule. I know how to use it for inline functions but what if I want to pass it to out-of-line JS function? I tried this:

rules: {
    startHours: {
        required: startTimeRequired(element)
    },

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just reference the function itself, element is passed for you:

```
rules: { startHours: { required: startTimeRequired },
```

startTimeRequired()  (if the parens are there) tells javascript to run the function then, which isn't what you want. You want to  tell the required event handler to throw 'event' at startTimeRequired.